# jQuery GetJSON / ajax returning error

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm currently testing out retrieving json from jquery.

The "service" url is:
http://imgsvc.heroku.com/images

*In case that doesn't work, the contents of the response are:*

```
[
"12345"
"39879827"
"9762974"
]
```

I have created a simple test.htm page (located on my local machine)

This is the jquery I'm using:

```
  $.ajax("http://imgsvc.heroku.com/images/?callback=?", {
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",

    error: function() { alert("error"); },

    success: function (data, text, xhqr) {
      $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        alert(item);
      });
    }
  });
```

In chrome, all I get is "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json"

I also get an alert pop up "error" - as I told it to do this when there is an error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a valid JSON.

```
[
"12345",
"39879827",
"9762974"
]
```

is correct. Also, you need callback() function from jsonp.

Comment: Updated url to include ?callback=?

Also, changed my demo service to valid json-
imgsvc.heroku.com/images

still have same error though

Comment: It was my "service" - i added support for the callback, and it works now. thanks!